# <ask> How to display output in other page

Tags: php

How to display output "paragraf & token" in other page php? I want to display paramater "paragraf & token" thanks before.

```
a.php

    function ringkasan($con, $isi){

    $paragraf = explode(". ", $isi);

    if(strlen($paragraf[count($paragraf)-1]) <= 1) {
        unset($paragraf[count($paragraf)-1]);
    }

    //1. Case Folding
    for($i=0; $i<count($paragraf); $i++){
        //Merubah ke huruf kecil
        $paragraf[$i] = strtolower($paragraf[$i]);
        //menghilangkan tanda baca
        // I wannat Display output this to other page =>  
        $paragraf[$i] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $paragraf[$i]);
    }

    //4. Tokenizing
    $token = Array();
    foreach($paragraf as $item){
        $tmp = explode(" ", $item);

        foreach($tmp as $x){
            //I wannat Display output this to other page =>   
            $token[] = $x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean? Perhaps provide description and example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wanna display output "paragraf & token" to other page ex. I have a.php, b.php, c.php. a.php have contain code above, then i wanna display output variable "paragraf & token" in a.php to b.php or c.php thanks before

Comment: You're probably on the right track with `$_SESSION` variables. Make sure you use `session_start()` at the top of the script.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is independent from inner page content, than you can move it to other file (lets call it `header.php`) and include that inside other pages:

```
[a.php/b.php/c.php]
require_once(__DIR__.'header.php');

// rest of code.
```

If it does have any dependency and you want to transfer it than use `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`:

```
[a.php]
<?php
session_start();
// ...
$_SESSION['paragraph_name'] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $paragraf[$i]);

[b.php]
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!-- ... -->
<section>
     <?php
     echo !empty($_SESSION['paragraph_name']) ? $_SESSION['paragraph_name'] : 'Default paragraph name';
     ?>
</section>
```